# Make it so pytest requires all tests to have globally unique names

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to make it so that pytest requires all my tests to have globally unique names? I often copy a test from one file to another and them modify it, but sometimes I forget to change the name, and it ends up confusing me later. Is there a pytest plugin or something that can do this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; in a sense the names would already be globally unique because of how the import system works (they would be namespaced by the package and/or module names)

Comment: You could write a hook (like `pytest_collection_modifyitems`) in your global `conftest.py` that checks that and issues a warning for duplicate names (provided they live in different modules/namespaces, of course, otherwise they will not show up).

Comment: While the function names do not have to be unique, I do salute the request as is a very good practice to have them globally unique. I just discovered a project that that >20 tests called just `test()`,... Did anyone ended up writing that hook?